# mCustomScrollbar doesn't work with html 5 audio player

Tags: jquery, scroll, custom-scrolling

i have a problem with pure html 5 audio player, inside the mCustomScrollbar scroller, when i try to drag the tracker of the player it goes crazy, the mouse is attached to the player tracker
here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/FhWez/10/embedded/result/
thank you.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />

<style>
.tracks
{
margin-left: 72px;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 150px;
width: 860px;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="playlist">
<div class="tracks">
<div class="track">
<div class="track-title">Around Mountains 2</div>
<div class="track-audio">
<audio src="http://mos.futurenet.com/intermusic/audio/samples/funk-demo-loops/GuitarD_90A-01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls="controls" />
</div>
<div class="track-download"></div>
</div>
<div class="track">
<div class="track-title">Around Mountains 2</div>
<div class="track-audio">
<audio src="http://mos.futurenet.com/intermusic/audio/samples/funk-demo-loops/GuitarD_90A-01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls="controls" />
</div>
<div class="track-download"></div>
</div>
<div class="track">
<div class="track-title">Around Mountains 2</div>
<div class="track-audio">
<audio src="http://mos.futurenet.com/intermusic/audio/samples/funk-demo-loops/GuitarD_90A-01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls="controls" />
</div>
<div class="track-download"></div>
</div>
<div class="track">
<div class="track-title">Around Mountains 2</div>
<div class="track-audio">
<audio src="http://mos.futurenet.com/intermusic/audio/samples/funk-demo-loops/GuitarD_90A-01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls="controls" />
</div>
<div class="track-download"></div>
</div>                     
</div>  
</div>

</div> <!-- /container -->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
$(window).load(function(){
$(".tracks").mCustomScrollbar({
theme:"dark-thick"
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```